# .display() not giving any result in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, mount

I have been using data bricks for quite some time now. recently i got a new Databricks environment and i also mounted azure ADLS gen 2 to my Databricks env. i tested the connection it looks good . but when i read any file from mount point , the code is just running and not showing any result. any idea what could be the reason? i even tried to read a csv file, its the same .

the code i am running is as below.

```
path = 'some/path/in/ADLS_Gen2/'
df= spark.read.json(path)
df.display()
```

also earlier when i mount ADLS i use to see that in DBFS explorer , but this one i am not able to.

```
dbutils.fs.ls(path)
```

this shows all the file present in perticulat folder of ADLS

Comment: Any error ? or is it just running ? try first to see if your spark is OK. Something like `spark.range(10).show()`. Is it working ?

Comment: Its just Running no errors , one day i left it for whole night ,morning it was still running .

Answer (score 0):

try prepending with "dbfs:" to tell spark that it should look through the Databricks file system.

Try

```
path = 'dbfs:/some/path/in/ADLS_Gen2/'
df= spark.read.json(path)
df.display()
```

If it does not work, I would try to find the diectory within the databricks catalog [image]

and copy the path directly from there with the Spark API format.

The last solution I am thinking is changing the API command to:

```
path = 'dbfs:/your/path/here'
spark.read.format('json').load(path).display()
```

Comment: `dbfs:` is default filesystem...

Comment: Edited with a third option

Comment: @Daniel Perez Efremova : thanks for ur response , really appreciate it.
but i already tried adding 'dbfs:/' before the path and also tried to take the path from Catalog.
the thing is i am not able to see that in catalog also .

Comment: Is the spark session healthy?